# IF with SUM in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table and it has an amount and remarks field. If the remarks is not 0.00, the query will get the SUM of amount, else it will get the remarks. but my query's just adding the remarks in the total sum of the query. Sorry for my bad english.

Here's the structure of my table:

```
amount    |    remarks     |    received    |    request
-------------------------------------------------------------
100.00    |    0.00        |    2016-01-01  |    Completed
100.00    |    0.00        |    2016-01-01  |    Completed
100.00    |    0.00        |    2016-01-01  |    Completed
100.00    |    500.00      |    2016-01-01  |    Completed
```

My query is:

```
SELECT if (remarks = 0.00, SUM(amount), SUM(remarks)) as AMT , received AS YY, request FROM tbldonation
WHERE request = 'Completed'
```

The result should be 800.00 but my result is 900.00, it will add the 100 with remark's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(remarks = 0.00, amount, remarks)) AS AMT, 
       received AS YY, 
       request 
FROM tbldonation
WHERE request = 'Completed'
```

Comment: I have an error "Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual "

Comment: @SeeMore Maybe there is a space inside `SUM()`?

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo error. It worked. Thank you mate.

Answer (score 0):

Just an other perspective using [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression.

**Query**

```
select sum(
             case remarks 
             when 0.00 then amount 
             else remarks end
) as AMT,
received AS YY, request 
from tbldonation
where request = 'Completed';
```